# Failing to load font after burning to disk

Tags: java, fonts, classloader, iso, truetype

I have an application which has a font stored within a jar file. It is loaded with:

```
public Font getChessFont()
{   

    InputStream in =  ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("fonts\\MERIFONTNEW.TTF");
    Font toReturn;
    try
    {
        toReturn = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, in);
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        toReturn = gameInformation;
    }
    toReturn = toReturn.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, squareSize);
    return toReturn;
}
```

When running the program from Eclipse or a jar file this code loads the font sucessfuly. However, after I put the jar files into an ISO image and mount them to a disk the files fail to load. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Resources paths usually should use forward slash (`/`) in the path (more like a URL) as this is a platform independent. I don't know if this is causing your problem; so just leaving as a comment.

Comment: I cleared my solution set and ran into the problem outlined here: http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg01881.html

After fixing that problem I followed your suggestion with the slashes and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect that. I will move my comment to an answer so you can mark this answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently my comment was enough to solve this. So the question can be "answered", I have added the comment as an answer:

Resource paths usually should use forward slash (/) in the path (more like a URL) as this is platform independent.

Comment: After fixing this problem: http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg01881.html and changing the slashes the program worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Are the files/JARs on the disk on the classpath?